# In App purchase restoration not working after releasing app to store

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have a very strange problem. I have implemented an In App Purchase mechanism for my non-consumable app. It works very fine and passed all of my tests. But after submitting app to store and downloading it, It's **Restore** mechanism doesn't work properly.

Here is the scenario: Downloading app from store. Make an in app purchase with my apple ID. Removed app. Reinstall it. ask for restore with the same apple ID and I got following error:"The apple ID you entered couldn't be found or your password was incorrect. please try again.". And It's just started store kit process.

Here comes my codes:

```
    SKProductsRequest *productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithArray:productIdentifiers]];
    productsRequest.delegate = self;
    [productsRequest start];
```

============comes response

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
        self.products = response.products;
        NSMutableArray * invalidProductIdentifiersMutable = [NSMutableArray new];

    for (NSString *invalidIdentifier in response.invalidProductIdentifiers) {
        [invalidProductIdentifiersMutable addObject:invalidIdentifier];
    }
    self.invalidProductIdentifiers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:invalidProductIdentifiersMutable];
    if (self.products) {
                [self restorePurchase];
    }
}
```

============start

```
NSURL *receiptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
NSData *receipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptURL];
if (!receipt) {
    SKReceiptRefreshRequest * request = [[SKReceiptRefreshRequest alloc] init];
    request.delegate = self;
    [request start];
}
[self registerAsPurchaseObserver];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
```

========result

```
-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [Delegate transactionDidFail];
}

- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
{
    NSURL *receiptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
    NSData *receipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptURL];
    if (receipt) {
        [Delegate transactionDidRestorePurchaseSuccessfullyWithReciept:receipt];
    }
    else{
        [Delegate transactionDidFail];
    }
}
```

I emphasis that it works correctly under development and passed all of my tests several times.
But it's not working after downloading from store and once again only restore is not working. Purchase is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with my app.  How I got it to work was to:

1. Delete app
2. Download app from the app store
3. Launch the app and click on the restore purchase button that calls:

   `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions]`

The problem maybe is that you're launching the app in Xcode?  Anyway, give these steps a shot.